# How to change every number of an HTML input form into a subscript while typing?

Tags: javascript, html, input, subscript, chemistry

I would like to create an HTML input form that converts every typed numerical value into a subscript. The numerical value that is typed into the input form, should immediately appear as a subscript while typing.

I am making a molar mass calculator for chemical formulas and it would be nice to show the correct form of a chemical formula. Users could, for example, type O2 into the input form and it should appear as O₂.

I have tried the following:

JavaScript:

```js
const inputFormula = document.getElementById("input-formula");

inputFormula.addEventListener("input", function () {
     inputFormula.value = inputFormula.value.replace(/(\d+)/g, "<sub>$1</sub>");
    });
```

On change of the input field, the JavaScript code will convert every number into a subscript, at least that was the idea, but it doesn't work.

HTML:

```html
<input type="text" id="input-formula" placeholder="formula" required>
```

However, when typing a number into the input field, the numbers are replaced with <*sub>"number"</*sub>, while I would like it to be replaced with the number displayed as subscript. Is this possible in HTML?

I added the * to prevent the sub tag from functioning as code

Any suggestions are welcome!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot use HTML to format text inside the typing area of an `<input>`. You can style that area with CSS to a limited extent.

Comment: That is because you cant use a HTML tag in an input. It will show as text not HTML.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vanowm/ygtqdh9L/